# Why won't my USB powered LED remain on until after the 3rd attempt to turn it on?

Tags: voltage, power, led

I have a USB powered LED that I use for late night desk work.  It's 8" long overall, housed in a bendy kind of stem with the last 1.5" being the light. It looks like a Popsicle stick that doubles in width for the last 1 1/2 inches. It is turned on by a touch sensor that is situated on the surface opposite the light.

Here's what happens every time I want to use it:
- I touch the sensor and the light comes on for a bit under 30 seconds and then goes out.
- I can immediately touch the sensor and turn it back on and again it goes out in about the same amount of time.
- I am unable to turn it on again until about 45 seconds have passed. But when I am able to turn it on again it will stay on as long as I want.

This has been its behavior ever since I got it about 2 years ago. I've moved it around to different sockets - powered by AC chargers, PC ports and monitor ports and it's always the same. I have several other lights all working with no problem. And I do mean that it's always the same, not just sometimes or often.  Always.

Is anyone able to deduce what is whack about this light?  It's just weird.

Comment: I tested as suggested and after rediscovering the LED in the freezer, your prediction was accurate - it lit and stayed the 1st time. So thank you for the magic trick. But you kinda put me into a deeper state of confusion.  I knew there was no chance of a fix that was worth fixing but I had hoped to understand why the 3rd attempt always worked.  Like it had to warm-up.  You say cool it down and that works even better. So I can either warm it up or cool it down to turn it on so it stays on. Doesn't that violate some law?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect heat to be an issue with the switch, cool down your light in the freezer then try it again to see if the delays get longer.